# How do I send separate form data for replies using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a messaging system installed on my site. For each message that a user receives I want to have a reply form, that knows to reply to the person who sent the original message.

I can get the forms to appear and messages to send, but the replies are going to the user who sent the last message received instead of the user who sent the posted message.

**HTML and Javascript:**

```
<!–– INBOX START ––>

          <div id="navitem1" onclick="navitem1(event)" class="navitem1"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-lg" id="navicon"></i><div class="redball"><div class="message_count"></div></div><p class="text">Inbox</p>

          </div>

          <div id="navitem1dropdown" class="navitem1content">
              <h3>Inbox</h3>
              <div class="sectionheader2"></div>
              <div class="inboxscroll">

              </div>

          </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.message_count').html('0');


 function load_unseen_messages(viewmsg = '')
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"inbox.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{viewmsg:viewmsg},
   dataType:"json",
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('.inboxscroll').html(data.messagehtml);
    if(data.message_count > 0)
    {
     $('.message_count').html(data.message_count);
    }
   }
  });
 }

 load_unseen_messages();

 $(document).on('click', '.navitem1', function(){
  $('.message_count').html('0');
  load_unseen_messages('yes');
 });

 setInterval(function(){ 
  load_unseen_messages();; 
 }, 5000);

});
</script>

<script>

$('#inboxForm').submit(function(){$('input[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled','disabled');});
  function replyPM(){
    var pmTextArea = $("#pmTextArea");
    var sendName = $("#pm_send_name");
    var sendID = $("#pm_send_id");
    var receiveName = $("#pm_receive_name");
    var receiveID = $("#pm_receive_id");
    var timesent = $("#pm_timesent");
    var url = "messages.php";

    $.post(url,{ message: pmTextArea.val(), sendername: sendName.val(), senderid: sendID.val(), recname: receiveName.val(), recID: receiveID.val(), time: timesent.val()  },    function(data){
      $("#interaction").html('Message sent successfully.').show().fadeOut(5000);
      document.inboxForm.pmTextArea.value='';
      });

  }

</script>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'class.channel.php';

$user_inbox = new USER();

$user_id = $_SESSION['userID'];
$user_name = $_SESSION['userName'];

if(isset($_POST["viewmsg"]))
{

if($_POST["viewmsg"] != '')
{
$stmt = $user_inbox->runQuery("UPDATE inbox SET status = 1 WHERE receive_id = ?");
$stmt->bindValue(1,$user_id);
$stmt->execute();
}

$stmt = $user_inbox->runQuery("SELECT * FROM inbox WHERE receive_id= ? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50");
$stmt->bindValue(1,$user_id);
$stmt->execute();
$messages = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$messagehtml = '';

if(count($messages) > 0)
 {
  foreach($messages as $message)
  {


  $messagehtml .= '


<div class="inboxsection"><h6>From:&nbsp'.$message["send_name"].'</h6><h6>'.$message["timesent"].'</h6><h6>Message:&nbsp</h6><img src="images/preview2.jpg" height="100%" width="100%" class="inboxvid">
  <h7>'.$message["comment"].'</h7>
<div style="clear:both;"><br><button id="reply" class="button" onclick="inboxmessage(event)">Reply</button>&nbsp<button id="archive" class="button">Archive</button>&nbsp<button id="delete" class="button">Delete</button></div>
</div>
  <div id="inboxmessage" class="messagearea">

  <form action="javascript:replyPM();" name="inboxForm" id="inboxForm" method="post">

                <input name="pm_send_id" id="pm_send_id" type="hidden" value="'.$user_id.'" />
                <input name="pm_send_name" id="pm_send_name" type="hidden" value="'.$user_name.'" />
                <input name="pm_receive_id" id="pm_receive_id" type="hidden" value="'.$message["send_id"].'" />
                <input name="pm_receive_name" id="pm_receive_name" type="hidden" value="'.$message["send_name"].'" />
                <input name="pm_timesent" id="pm_timesent" type="hidden" value="" />               

                <div id="interaction"></div>
                <br>
                <p style="color:#fff;">Message:</p>
                <textarea name="pmTextArea" id="pmTextArea"></textarea>
                <p style="color:#fff;">Attach A Video:</p>
                <input name="pmSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>

  </div>

<div class="sectionheader3"></div>
   ';

  }
 }
 else
 {
  $messagehtml .= '<div><h2 style="color: #4b8ed3; padding: 10px;">No Messages Found<h2></div>';
 }

$count = $user_inbox->runQuery("SELECT * FROM inbox WHERE receive_id= ? AND status= 0");
$count->bindValue(1,$user_id);
$count->execute();
$countresult = $count->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

if(count($countresult) > 0){
  $message_count = count($countresult);
}
else{
  $message_count = 0;
}

header('Content-type: application/json');
$inbox_array = array('messagehtml'=>$messagehtml,'message_count'=>$message_count);
echo json_encode($inbox_array);

}
?>
```

Comment: "but the reply defaults to the last message received instead of the posted message" .. can you expand on that more.

Comment: Essentially, the replies are going to the user who sent the last message received instead of the user who sent the posted message.

Comment: In your javascript function replyPM() you are referencing element IDs. These should be unique. If you are duplicating IDs on the page then the values from the first instance of that ID will be used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon creating/inserting your replies, have a reference field like `parentId` that would reference it to the original message being replied to.

And with that you can get the information of the user if you have like a reference column to your user table.  ex `createdBy`

I can update this answer, and give you more specifics you if give a column list of your `inbox` table.

Get the Primary ID of the POSTED message

base on your table design I would do it like this:

```
$postedMessageId = $_GET['id'];// you can pass the id however you want.this is just a sample

INSERT INTO inbox ("parentId","comment",....) VALUES ( <postedMessageId>, <comment>,.... )
```

With that you can now reference all the replies, using the `parentId` column, by using JOIN.

Comment: Okay, columns for `inbox` are `id,send_id,receive_id,status,timesent,comment,send_name,rec_name`. I'm not sure what you mean by reference field, but from what I understand I need each instance of this form to have a unique id?

Comment: Always get the PRIMARY KEY of the posted message. That is the unique ID that you need to, include on when inserting your replies, to your table.

Comment: Thank you Mark. Is there any way I can append these IDs to the form itself since the form data only wants to send to the first inbox message? In other words, I need a way to have a unique form for each reply without redoing the form html 50+ times..

Comment: on your ajax post function. include the ID of the posted message being replied to. `url:"inbox.php?id="+id,`

Comment: than you can catch it. using `$_GET['id']`